# Undefined control sequence (in Wiley journal)

Tags: errors, align

I need to write the equation given below.

I got the error:

```
Undefined control sequence
```

I have tried a lot.

LaTeX template was downloaded from the link given below.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1099-1131/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm

It uses `WileyNJD-v2` class file.

My code contains:

```
\documentclass[AMA,demo,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}&{P_{{\mathop{\text{c}}},{{d1}}}}(r_{1},\phi_{1},T) ={\mathds{P}}\left[{\text{SINR} _{d1}} \geq T \right]= \mathds{P}\left[\frac{{{P_d}{d_0^{ - {\alpha _d}}}g}}{{I_{d1} + {I_{u1}} + N}} \geq T \right]\notag\\&\quad = \mathds{P}\left[g \geq \frac{{T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}\left(I_{d1} + {I_{u1}} + N\right) }}{{{P_d}}}\right] \notag \\&\quad \mathop = \limits^{(a)}{\mathop{\mathds{E}_{{I_{d1}},I_{u1}}}}\left[{\exp \left(\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}(I_{d1} + {I_{u1}} + N) }}{{{P_d}}}\right)} \right] \notag\\&\quad \mathop = \limits^{(b)} {{\mathds{E}}_{I_{d1}}}\left[{\exp \left(\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}I_{d1}}}{{{P_d}}}\right)} \right] {{\mathds{E}}_{{I_{u1}}}}\left[{\exp \left(\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}{I_{u1}}}}{{{P_d}}}\right)} \right] \notag \\&\qquad \times \exp \left({\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}N}}{{{P_d}}}} \right)\tag{21}\end{align}
hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: off-topic: `amsmath` automatically loads `amstext` so there's no need to do it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your example to use `article` so I could run it

```
%\documentclass[AMA,demo,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\begin{document}


\begin{align}&{P_{{\mathop{\text{c}}},{{d1}}}}(r_{1},\phi_{1},T) =
{\mathds{P}}\left[{\text{SINR} _{d1}} \geq T \right]= \mathds{P}\left[\frac{{{P_d}{d_0^{ - {\alpha _d}}}g}}{{I_{d1} + {I_{u1}} + N}} 
\geq T \right]\notag\\
&\quad = 
\mathds{P}\left[g \geq \frac{{T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}\left(I_{d1} + {I_{u1}} + N\right) }}{{{P_d}}}\right] \notag \\
&\quad \mathop = 
\limits^{(a)}{\mathop{\mathds{E}_{{I_{d1}},I_{u1}}}}\left[{\exp \left(\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}(I_{d1} + {I_{u1}} + N) }}{{{P_d}}}\right)} \right] \notag\\&\quad \mathop = 
\limits^{(b)} {{\mathds{E}}_{I_{d1}}}\left[{\exp \left(\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}I_{d1}}}{{{P_d}}}\right)} \right] {{\mathds{E}}_{{I_{u1}}}}\left[{\exp \left(\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}{I_{u1}}}}{{{P_d}}}\right)} \right] \notag \\
&\qquad \times \exp \left({\frac{{ - T {d_0^{{\alpha _d}}}N}}{{{P_d}}}} \right)\tag{21}\end{align}

hello
\end{document}
```

which gives the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...1}}}}(r_{1},\phi _{1},T) = {\mathds 
                                                  {P}}\left [{\text {SINR} _...
l.17 ...}}N}}{{{P_d}}}} \right)\tag{21}\end{align}

?
```

`\mathds` is for double struck letters, you could use the  amsfonts version and `\mathbb`  if you add `\usepackage{amsfonts}` or `\mathds` is from the package `dsfont` so add `\usepackage{dsfont}`